# Validation data performing worse than training data in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am training a CNN on some text data. The sentences are padded and embedded and fed to a CNN. The model architecture is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, embedding_dims, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())

model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(25, activation = 'relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How much text? What's the NN supposed to predict?

Perhaps the model isn't complex enough. Try increasing the number of neurons in the Dense layers, as well as adding more layers.

Answer (score 1):

You model is over-fitting so the best practice is:

- add layers and preferably that goes in the power of 2

instead of

```
  model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
```

use

```
  model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
```

and go with 512 128 64 32 16

- add some dropout layers  preferably after two layers.
- train on bigger data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing BatchNormalization and adding more Convolutional and Pooling Layer that may increase your accuracy.

You can also check out this -:
https://forums.fast.ai/t/batch-normalization-with-a-large-batch-size-breaks-validation-accuracy/7940